# How to fix duplicate classes in gradle build for android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, admob, google-play-services, androidx

I am trying to add ads in the build.gradle. However, it doesn't seem to be working.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "br.com.alessanderleite.catchtheballgame"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
  }



dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
}
```

Error:

```
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0)
```

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
```

This version uses the support libraries and you can't use androidx and support libraries together.

Use an [update version](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019) of ads migrated to androidx.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
```